# Autocomplete SQL query in db.execute('') on VScode

Tags: python, sql, flask, visual-studio-code

When writing SQL query in python (Flask, if that's necessary) execute(), is there a setting or extensions that would recognize SQL keywords like SELECT, UPDATE, and suggest them with IntelliSense or the like?

Right now the query is recognized as in the picture and keywords are not being suggested.

[SQL query keywords in VScode are not recognized (the whole query is green)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2LqI.png)

Comment: please read SO topic: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. spend time to type the image text. this is a good mannered way of asking on SO. BTW, your picture does not demostrate the problem.

Comment: @yvw thanks for the suggestion, I will try to improve. Regarding the picture, I wanted to show how VScode doesn't recognize keywords in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you're just putting in a string into `execute()` that is later read by SQLAlchemy (which I assume you're using). These aren't actually python keywords which IntelliSense can predict. However, you can use the SQLAlchemy ORM, or the higher level query object, which does not use SQL keywords but python methods to manipulate your database. Using this, you might find that IntelliSense can find the definition/declaration of the SQLAlchemy method and offer the usual pointers and helpers it does.

There are other advantages of using the higher level query class of SQLAlchemy, a significant one being you are less likely to be subject to SQL injections and attacks. Because you are executing raw SQL with the `execute()` command and simply putting an id from the session in, an attacker could alter the session value and inject harmful SQL into your application.

Anyway, that's beside the point but I thought it was worth letting you know.

Comment: That's false. Some IDEs like IntelliJ allow you to inject database context into strings. Not only giving you syntax highlighting, but also table, column, function, etc. intellisense suggestions.

Though I do not believe this is possible in VSCode.